# Connecting on VPN, disconnects the communication with local Host-only VMware

Tags: vpn, vmware

Connecting on VPN to office, disconnects the communication with my local VMware PC, set with Network connection as Host - only ( A private network shared with host) .
Should be a case of address colition due to non global ip address assignment.

I use Cisco anyconnect security mobility client. Please help to understand the issue, and alternatives.

Comment: Without additional information like routing tables and/or a network diagram it will be hard to give a useful answer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving us a lot of details like routing tables, but one thing I've seen quite often which may cause this is situations where all network traffic is routed via the VPN connection, isolating the machine from the local network.

Comment: Hi Teun, would you mind adding a comment requesting the details that you need from the OP to make this a more practical answer?

Comment: Of course, done!